# IE7 not displaying scrollbars automatically?

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, overflow

I wanted to know if there was a way to fix scrollbar issue I'm having with IE7.

Here is my CSS:

```
.gridContainer {
    height: 500px; 
    width: 410px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #6699CC;
}
.Grid {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.Grid td {
    height: 13px;
    min-width: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #C4DDFF;
}
.GridHeader {
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border-bottom: #999;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="gridContainer">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" GridLines="None" CssClass="Grid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AllowSorting="True" onsorting="GridView2_Sorting">
        <RowStyle CssClass="GridItem" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="SelectAll2(this);" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True"
                SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Position Type" HeaderText="Position Type"
                SortExpression="Position Type" />
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAltItem" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

It works fine in other browsers, but for some reason not in IE7.

*Edited for clarification:*

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: There is a `div` with a fixed `width` and `height` and inside it there is a `gridview`. If the `gridview`'s width or height exceeds the fixed size of the `div`, I'd like the scroll bars to appear on the `div`.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you're trying to do and the result?  You've left it up to our imagination here.

Comment: Can you provide a working example with actual HTML? What you have provided as HTML isn't actually HTML. It's a lot easier to figure out what is not working when there is something real to play around with.

Comment: please add the asp.net tag to this question

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, and then you can remove the ASP.NET tag and have a better chance of solving it!

Answer (score 0):

In your .gridContainer class set overflow: scroll;

This will add scroll bars to the div if the inside content grows past its set width or height.

Comment: `overflow: scroll` adds scroll bars regardless of the size of the content. I believe the most appropriate here would be `overflow: auto` (only displaying scroll bars when content is larger than parent). At least that's what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Examples) says